# Process a string in TSQL to DateTime with Time Zone

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, type-conversion, azure-sql-database, datetime-format

I am having a particular string of the format of date time with time zone. I need to convert the string to DateTime with TimeZone and also process the same and convert to UTC Time.

```
DECLARE @T AS VARCHAR(100)
SET @T = '2018-12-04T10:23:34+05:30'
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,@T,127),CONVERT(DATETIME,@T) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
```

Result

```
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

I have also tried with out the conversion parameter 127 but still returns the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this?

```
DECLARE @T AS VARCHAR(100)
SET @T = '2018-12-04T10:23:34+05:30';

SELECT CONVERT(datetimeoffset,@T,127)
      ,CONVERT(datetimeoffset,@T,127)  AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
      ,CAST(CONVERT(datetimeoffset,@T,127)  AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS DATETIME2);
```

Just convert to `dateimeoffset` and then to `UTC`.